# How to make this code work ?? ( discord.py )

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Ok, so I want to remove a role from a user but it don't work ( the command is : $rmv_role @user )

CODE :
( it's not all of the code just the part with the command )

```
@bot.command(name='rmv_role', description="description for help command")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)

async def rmv_role(ctx,arg):
    user_id = ''.join(c for c in arg if c.isdigit())
    guild = ctx.guild
    user = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_members(), id=user_id)
    role_id = 999988854696194048
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
    await ctx.reply(f"th user :{arg} no longer has the role!")
    await bot.remove_roles(user,role)
```

Comment: Use [`user.remove_roles(role)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles) instead of `bot.remove_roles(user,role)`. Make sure your bot has the required permissions to change user roles.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full traceback of any error you are facing (as a code block). As well, please include a [mcve] (emphasis on *minimal*) omitting any tokens. For more information, please see [ask]. "It doesn't work" is not an adequate problem statement as SO is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Made a Bot Couple Months Ago, I had This Problem But I solved it My Self,
I had a Data Frame Like This

```
main.py
Commands (Folder)
  -> utility.py
```

I just Linked The Main File to My Command Files so Instead Of `@bot.command()`, I had `@commands.command()`

You Don't Worry About The `self` (It Refers To your Prefix in My Code), If you have any other Doubts Regarding My Code Just Comment Down :

Code:

```
   @commands.command(name='rmv_role', description="description for help command")
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
    async def rmv_role(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
      print("open")
      guild = ctx.guild
      role_id =  999988854696194048
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
      await ctx.reply(f"th user :{member.name} no longer has the role!")
      await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Note That I Changed Your `args` to `member: discord.Member` Cause You dont Have to `get` the User with `discord.Member` Just Ping The Person!

I removed the `user` and `user_id` because of That As Well!

I tested and Checked The Code in My Bot Thats Why I took 20 Mins!

Hope This Helps, Comment If You have Any Doubt About this Or wanna learn about these `self` or `@commands.command()` more! I am Happy To Help!

Answer (score 1):

So, finaly I changed my code and now it looks like this :

```
@bot.command(name='rmv_role', description="description for help command")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)

async def rmv_role(ctx,user: discord.Member):
    guild = ctx.guild
    role_id = 999988854696194048
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
    await user.remove_roles (role)
```